# Threaded Haskell Program Not Terminating Immediately

Tags: sockets, haskell, concurrency

I have a simple program for a chat server in Haskell. I want the user to be able to connect to the chat server, and be able to type "quit()" to leave. I am currently running it all in ghci. Here is the code:

(Edit: Running on Windows 10 with GHCi, version 9.4.5)

```hs
import Network.Socket
import Control.Monad
import Control.Concurrent
import System.IO
import Control.Monad.Fix

connectToChatRoom :: IO ()
connectToChatRoom = do
    addrinfos <- getAddrInfo
                    Nothing
                    (Just "localhost")
                    (Just "9999")
    let serveraddr = head addrinfos
    serverSock <- socket (addrFamily serveraddr) Stream defaultProtocol
    connect serverSock (addrAddress serveraddr)
    hdl <- socketToHandle serverSock ReadWriteMode   -- make a handle
    hSetBuffering hdl NoBuffering
    listenThread <- forkIO (clientListener hdl)  -- open a new thread that listens
    clientSender hdl -- this thread now sends messages
    putStrLn "####### Left Chat #######"
    killThread listenThread        
    close serverSock

clientSender :: Handle -> IO ()
clientSender hdl = fix $ \loop -> do
    msg <- getLine -- read message from user
    when (msg /= "quit()") $ hPutStrLn hdl msg >> loop -- if not "quit()" send msg and continue looping


clientListener :: Handle -> IO ()
clientListener hdl = fix $ \loop -> do
    msg <- hGetLine hdl -- listen for msg from server
    putStrLn msg -- print to stdout
    loop
```

In ghci:

```
ghci> connectToChatRoom
Here is a message to send
From User 4: Here is a message sent from another term.
Now I want to leave
quit()
####### Left Chat #######
```

All looks good, but that program has not terminated, it is just waiting.
After "quit()" is sent, I expect `clientSender` to leave the `fix`, which I can confirm it does because the left chat message is posted, but I am left hanging UNTIL another user sends a chat. It seems like `killThread listenThread` does not terminate the `clientListener` function. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Any additional comments on the way the code runs is also appreciated.

Here is the code for the server, if it is important:

```hs
type Msg = (ID, String)
type ID = Int

chatRoomServer :: IO ()
chatRoomServer = do
    addrinfos <- getAddrInfo
                    (Just (defaultHints {addrFlags = [AI_PASSIVE]}))
                    Nothing
                    (Just "9999")
    let serveraddr = head addrinfos
    sock <- socket (addrFamily serveraddr) Stream defaultProtocol -- make socket
    bind sock (addrAddress serveraddr) -- bind socket to port
    listen sock 1 -- set up socket listener
    chan <- newChan
    _ <- forkIO $ fix $ \loop -> do -- in a tutorial, something about reading the initial channel
      (_, _) <- readChan chan
      loop
    listenForConnections sock chan -- loops waiting to accept connections

listenForConnections :: Socket -> Chan Msg -> IO ()
listenForConnections sock chan = fix loop_ 1
    where loop_ loop idNum = do
            (clientSock, _) <- accept sock
            _ <- forkIO $ manageConnection clientSock idNum chan
            loop (idNum + 1)


manageConnection :: Socket -> ID -> Chan Msg -> IO ()
manageConnection sock idNum chan = do
    let broadcast msg = writeChan chan msg -- send message to all users
    hdl <- socketToHandle sock ReadWriteMode
    hSetBuffering hdl NoBuffering
    commline <- dupChan chan
    _ <- forkIO $ fix $ \loop -> do -- listen for msg to user
        (idNum', msg) <- readChan commline
        when (idNum' /= idNum) $ hPutStrLn hdl ("From User " ++ show idNum' ++ ": " ++ msg)
        loop
    fix $ \loop -> do    -- listen for msg from user
        msg <- hGetLine hdl
        broadcast (idNum, msg)
        loop
```

Comment: I don't shure that it help but there is a bug. From documentation on `socketToHandle`: "... you should avoid doing any more operations on the Socket after calling socketToHandle. To close the Socket after socketToHandle, call hClose on the Handle."

Comment: Are you running on Windows or Linux, and what version of GHC are you using?

Comment: Running on Windows 10 with `GHCi, version 9.4.5`

Comment: @freestyle thanks.  I changed the line
`close serverSock` to `hClose hServer`, 
but I don't think it fixed the issue.

Comment: @Tristan You think or you known? Remember that you are in GHCi, don't forget to reload module before retest.

Comment: @freestyle It had definitely not fixed the issue I have been having, it still does not terminate until another user sends a message.

Comment: @Tristan Well, in such a situation, I would try to understand where exactly I have a hang. Try to `putStrLn` some message after `killThread listenThread` and after `hClose hdl`. This will show where exactly you have a hang.

Comment: @freestyle That's a great suggestion and I should have done that first. I did get it working by adding a check right before reading from the handle. I do a check with `hReady hdl`.

Comment: @Tristan And how your code looks like now? Another hint on problem from `throwTo`: "If the target thread is currently making a foreign call, then the exception will not be raised (and hence throwTo will not return) until the call has completed." So, I thing that calling `hGetLine hdl` internally doing foreign call especially under Windows.

Comment: @Tristan I think you should call `hClose hdl` before call `killThread listenThread`.

Comment: @Tristan Moreover, after `hClose hdl` you should not to call `killThread listenThread` if I understood correctly, becouse `hClose hdl` rises an exception `IOError` in `hGetLine hdl` and the thread will be terminated (becouse exception will not be handled).

Answer (score 4):

This problem seems specific to running the client under GHCi under Windows.  I found I was able to duplicate your problem running the client under GHCi version 9.2.5 running on Windows 10, but if I compiled the client and ran it as an executable, it exited normally, and running under Linux it worked correctly whether compiled or run under GHCi.

The `killThread` function raises a `ThreadKilled` exception in the target thread using `throwTo`, and as the [documentation for that function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:throwTo) explains, the exception is not guaranteed to be delivered immediately, and `killThread` blocks by design until the exception is delivered.

That appears to be what you're seeing here.  For some reason, the main thread is not able to deliver the exception to the target thread while it is waiting on `hGetLine`, and it requires an additional line of chat to be processed so `hGetLine` can return in the target thread, allowing the exception to be delivered and  `killThread` to return in the main thread.

I can't explain *exactly* why the exception can't be delivered to the thread while it's waiting on `hGetLine`, but only under GHCi and only under Windows, except to note that the GHC Windows runtime has historically had a lot of problems like this, and the priority has been on making things work correctly for compiled code, not for making things work correctly under GHCi.

So, my advice would be to just ignore the problem.  Note that in a "real" client program, there's no reason to kill any threads when the user quits the program.  Just end the main thread -- all other child threads will be killed automatically and immediately.

Comment: FWIW, it can actually be meaningful to kill threads before exiting if there are exciting resources where you want to do more graceful cleanup than what would happen by just not using them any more. A real-world example I had to deal with recently: on my machine, exiting a program with memory allocated on the GPU sometimes causes crashes, but releasing that memory before exiting is rock solid. (Presumably this is because of a bug in the driver or similar, but blaming somebody else doesn't make the problem go away...)

Answer (score 0):

From documentation on `socketToHandle`:

> ... you should avoid doing any more operations on the Socket after calling socketToHandle. To close the Socket after socketToHandle, call hClose on the Handle.

So you should call `hClose` on the socket handle. But it won't help with the hang.

I agree with @K. A. Buhr, looks like `killThread` hang because can't deliver exception to the thread. From documentation on `throwTo` (`killThread` call `throwTo`):

> If the target thread is currently making a foreign call, then the exception will not be raised (and hence throwTo will not return) until the call has completed.

So, maybe, implementation of `hGetLine` on socket handle especially under Windows doing a foreign call and that's why there is a hang.

I think proper solution will be does not killing the thread explicitly but just call `hClose` on the socket handle which will lead to throw `IOError` on `hGetLine` and the thread will be terminated.

There is another problem. Dangerous to "open" a handle separately to "close" it. If some exception will happen between open/close handle than a handle may leave long time in open state. One way to fix that problem is to use the `bracket` function.

```
...
bracket (socketToHandle serverSock ReadWriteMode) hClose $ \hdl -> do
    void $ forkIO (clientListener hdl)
    clientSender hdl
```